# Node.js and WinLess are not showing error messages, Do I need to put Less.js In Developer mode?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, less

I have downloaded and installed node.js and less.js using npm but when I compile my less files, using node.js command line (Using the following Command)

```
lessc -x style.less ../css/style.css
```

less.js does not report any errors, it returns successful but, my CSS file remains unchanged, and the date modified does not change.

I do however get it to compile when I remove an imported file ( My fonts file). My best guess at the moment is that I need to put less in Development mode to show errors, but I'm not sure how to do that through node.js.

Another note, I have been using WinLess, and it too stopped reporting errors and ceased to compile CSS files for no apparent reason. WinLess actually gives me a successful popup but, the same unmodified CSS file issue occurs.

I have boiled down the issue to one line, when I remove this line, it compiles successfully. But why will lessc not show me the error for this line?

```
@import url("//5555.5555.55555/5555/5555"); // URL info changed for security reasons.
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "development mode" in `lessc` (as it is the default and the only mode of the command line compiler). `lessc` always report compilation errors to the console so most likely some error occurs before `lessc` is invoked if you can't see any (i.e. it looks like something goes wrong with the `node` itself and/or console environment).

Comment: I wasnt sure about development mode in lessc, but im facing the same issue with WinLess.

Comment: Is there a way to view Node errors?

Comment: Well, the node errors are also printed to the console. Speaking of `@import url("//5555.5555.55555/5555/5555");`, hmm, is that Less or CSS file? And if it's Less, is there any special reason to import remote file instead of local? Probably some unstable connection to this remote address causes `node` to bail out silently (though normally `lessc` reports `FileError: resource '...' gave this Error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` if it can't access such address).

Comment: Its a URL to a font provider used in CSS (Not a LESS file), looks like i don't need it (For now anyway, fonts seem to be working) But it doesn't give A single error, just returns nothing (Which i'm assuming is successful) Maybe node started suppressing errors by default?

Comment: Hmm, strange, if it's css file (or more specifically it end with `css` extension)) then Less should just leave the statement as is w/o initiating any connection and now I wonder what problem it can be then (as it appears to be just the same "plain string" as others...). As for `node` errors, AFAIK it always prints any errors too so it could be something *really* unexpected if it does not... hmm, I've run out of ideas :).